# Do browsers stil animate invisible content?

Tags: performance, css

When a page contains CSS3 animations that are below the fold, or that get hidden as the user scrolls down, should you apply a class using Javascript to stop the animation, or do browsers not animate invisible elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though browsers will not *draw* elements that are outside of the viewport I'm still pretty sure they will continue to update the css properties as determined by the css animation even when the element is not visible.

This is needed in order to be able to listen for animation events, or to be able to read the value of an animated css property at any given time.

So, in theory you might improve performance by removing the css class that animates the element, but unless you have very complex animations or animate hundreds of elements I wouldn't really worry about it.

"Drawing" is the most expensive part usually, especially if you're animating things such as colors, which causes a *repaint*. However, if you're animating a translation or rotation using a css transform the browser usually doesn't need to do a repaint each frame. Instead it can just paint the element once and send it to the GPU as a texure and let the GPU translate or rotate it each frame, which is crazy fast since it's all hardware accelerated.